# Sending Parse push notification to multiple platforms using the same keys

Tags: mobile, parse-platform, push-notification

Is it possible to use the same client_key and application_id for multiple application? I have an application which is written in both iOS and Android and I want to see if I can use the same keys to send push to both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the appropriate key for the right environment, but you can push to multiple OS's. For example, using the REST API key I can push notifications to both Android and iOS from my server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my certificate was not good. I replaced the certificate with a new generated certificate and it worked. Make sure you don't rename the generated p12 file to something else. In my case I believe I had renamed the file and that's why it was not recognized by parse.